# How do e-commerce apps like Amazon get to know which item user clicked

Tags: android, e-commerce

I've been planning to work on a e-commerce app in android for a while and now I'm stuck at a question that is how do e-commerce apps like Amazon etc. get to know that which item did the user clicked upon to load the next screen(item details).
I know that by using recycler view we can get clicked item's position and then handle it but like for a big app I don't find this approach to be appropriate. So how do others do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, your items in the recyclerview will have `ids`, a unique identifier. All we do is pass the id to the next activity, from there we request for the details of the item using the id and populate the view.

Or if I don't understand your question enlighten me more

Comment: Okay but for eg. let's say we have 100 items on our homepage so we have to store a unique ID for each item? And if it is like this, so apps like Amazon who have lots and lots of items, how do they handle this? They too store unique IDs?

Comment: Its like this: your website has items listed in the homepage, automatically the items should have unique ids attached to each of them(unless its bad designing from the website end), the ids are part of data associated with each items(including item-name, image), so when you populate your recyclerview, you'll also have access to the ids. So in the website, when a user clicks an item, the item id is appended to an URL which will display full details of the item. Its the same with the recyclerview in android

Comment: Okay so that means that I have to associate my recycler view item's unique ID with the position on which the item is in my recycler view so that I can get the position on which the user clicked and then grab the data according to it?

Comment: Yes. Every itemview in recyclerview will have its own clicklistener, so when the user clicks the item, you get the item data by the position of the item.

Comment: Okayy Thank You so much and sorry for my silly question! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯